# SOL Change is wrong

Tags: transfer, sol

SOL Change in the following transaction is wrong.
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2zSnKNdmAmR9ZJzwLg7z3CDLxJo9pv49iRc3xT1xtt5rzkTdfTbmjjGwByL96DdLhYb2isfnYzuSktgbdE15k8uD

HXBzECywEz6uaaXkb6ziM3vWsRMvpPAncFGnyi4MMhZQ transferred 1 SOL to 9YUJruF9LpPG2mPTSyxR7wcjv2vKGi1FEZU6ycmh99r3.

However, 9YUJruF9LpPG2mPTSyxR7wcjv2vKGi1FEZU6ycmh99r3 received only 0.009997561 SOL. What's the cause?

Answer (score 4):

The receiving account had "rent" deducted from it when referenced in that transaction, which is not reflected well in the pre / post SOL balances.

You can see the cost of rent using `solana rent`. Since it's a system account with 0 space, you can run:

```
$ solana rent 0
Rent per byte-year: 0.00000348 SOL
Rent per epoch: 0.000002439 SOL
Rent-exempt minimum: 0.00089088 SOL
```

Here, we see that the rent per epoch is `0.000002439`. The amount received was `◎0.009997561`, which is exactly `0.01 - 0.000002439`, so the receiving account had its rent deducted.

Note that this is an old transaction, so you will not see this behavior anymore on any network. Rent has been removed, so all accounts must provide enough to be "rent-exempt", or the transaction will fail.